# Exchange - non-received mail return code 5.7.0 Access denied

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2003

I am experiencing strange problems on our Exchange servers (exchange 2003 SP2); lately some domains can't communicate with our server.

We are able to send messages outside without any problems, but we can't receive from some (not all) outside domains.

The SMTP connection is established correctly, but some senders get an error message saying the message couldn't be delivered.

Here is what I see on my SMTP logs :

```
[...] EHLO - +sender.fr 250 0 314 23 0 SMTP - - - -
[...] MAIL - +FROM:<test@sender.fr> 250 0 70 68 0 SMTP - - - -
[...] RCPT - +TO:<test@mydomain.fr> 250 0 0 39 0 SMTP - - - -
[...] QUIT - sender.fr 240 4219 71 20148 4125 SMTP - - - -
```

No DATA or BDAT command is visible on the log.

The sender get an error message like this :

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; sender.fr
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: F3491132B0
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; bob@sender.fr
Arrival-Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 18:00:56 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; myself@mydomain.fr
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; host smtp.mydomain.fr[x.x.x.x] said: 550 5.7.0
Access Denied (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

I have no trace of this mail in the Exchange message tracker.

The strange thing is it was working before. The only thing that I did lately was setting-up a new Exchange 2010 server, however it is not in use yet (incoming mails are still directed to the 2003 front end).

Mails goes through our UTM without problems (fortigate 600C), the sender have been whitelisted there just to be sure and it changed nothing.

I have also disabled pipelining on our exchange servers, as I saw it could cause problems sometimes.

This happens only with some domains (not all). I have contacted the IT from some and it looks like we are the only one they have problem with.

I have spent quite some time on this and have no idea what's wrong, if anybody has an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really install Exchange 2010 and then not have it used, as Exchange doesn't work like that. Therefore I would check the Exchange 2010 server is configured correctly. Enable anonymous authentication on the Default Receive Connector and restart the MS Exchange Transport service.

It isn't clear from your error whether Exchange directly answers the SMTP call, or whether the appliance does. That can give you an indication of where the problem may be.

Comment: The Exchange 2010 is used but for a different domain (mydomain.eu), and it has been configured and is working correctly - with the eu domain. Anonymous authentication is enabled on the Default Receive Connector. I am positive it's Exchange that is answering the SMTP call and not the appliance.

Comment: Unless it is a completely different Windows forest, then the SMTP domain has nothing to do with it. That is a configuration step, it has no effect on Exchange processing email for the entire environment. 
Message tracking only shows the message once it has been successfully delivered to the server. 
What else is on the Exchange 2003 server? AV? Does it have the correct exclusions?

Comment: It is indeed in the same windows forest. We have nothing else running on the server and I removed the AV a couple days ago to be sure this was not the cause of our problem.